# Future ignores await in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I'm trying to make a version control for my application. In other words, trying to connect to firebase documents, pick version number from there and compare it with value from shared preferences in order to decided if it's required to update the information.

I've followed the official tutorial on Futures.

here is my code:

```
@override
  void initState(){
    loadit();
  }

Future _getIntVersionFromSharedPref() async {
    await Firestore.instance.collection('DataIndex')
        .document('dbversion').snapshots().listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        fbVersion = event['currentversion'];
      });
      print('_getIntVersionFromSharedPref() future -> $fbVersion');
      return fbVersion;
    });
  }

  Future<String> loadit() async {
    var myFBversion = await _getIntVersionFromSharedPref();
    print('loadit future -> $myFBversion');
  }
```

However I endup with the following console output:

```
I/flutter: loadit future -> null
I/flutter: _getIntVersionFromSharedPref() future -> 1
```

Why would it fire null right away without waiting for the value? According to the official tutorial it should be executed in turn.

Comment: I'm not sure about firebase because I have never used it, but i think you are mixin await and then. You should only use one of the two. If you use await you should create a value or if you use then you don't need to do await (I think listen is the same as then).

Comment: @AyadRocketfy There are no instances of `then` in the OP's code.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how the OP's code is even compiling. There is a method that returns a `Future<String>` but has no return statement and they're awaiting something that isn't a future.

Answer (score 1):

[listen()](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.12.0-51.0.dev/dart-async/Stream/listen.html) doesn't return a Future, so you can't await it.  It returns a StreamSubscription object asynchronously, and you must handle the ongoing results of the query within your stream handler function.  When you are done with the Stream, you should unsubscribe from the stream using the StreamSubscription.

If you just want a single snapshot of the document, don't use [snapshots()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html) at all.  Just use [get()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/get.html) to get a single snapshot as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read).

Answer (score -1):

Listen isn't part of the dart `Future` API, so that `listen` callback isn't tied to the Promise that is implicitly returned from `_getIntVersionFromSharedPref`.

I think you need to manually return a Promise from that method, and resolve it from your listen callback. You can manually resolve a `Future` like this with the [`Completer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) class.

Something like this:

```dart
Future _getIntVersionFromSharedPref() async {
  var completer = Completer<num>();
  await Firestore.instance.collection('DataIndex')
      .document('dbversion').snapshots().listen((event) {
    setState(() {
      fbVersion = event['currentversion'];
    });
    print('_getIntVersionFromSharedPref() future -> $fbVersion');
    completer.complete($fbVersion);
  });

  // This will be returned right away, but anything that awaits it will block
  // until the callback above has completed the future.
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: This may work, but it's useless to use a completer when you can just obtain a single snapshot as Doug's answer suggests.